# Kendo UI - Texfield not showing in MultiSelect when Value is 0

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using Kendo Multiselect for angular 2.

here's my **template** code:

```
<kendo-multiselect #groupingsDropdown
                   [data]="fixedData.PossibleValuesForGroupingsAndSortings"
                   [filterable]="true"
                   [textField]="'Name'"
                   [valueField]="'Type'"
                   [value]="definitionDetails.Groupings"
                   (valueChange)="setGroupingsArray(groupingsDropdown.value)">

</kendo-multiselect>
```

and here's my **controller** code:

```
public setGroupingsArray(values: any) {
    if (values) {
        if (values.length <= 3) {

            this.definitionDetails.Groupings = values;
            this.setGroupBreakArray();
            console.log(this.definitionDetails.Groupings);

        } else {
            this.definitionDetails.Groupings = this.definitionDetails.Groupings.map(item => item);
        }
    }
}
```

It works great, however I found an error. when my `valueField` equals 0, it doesn't show the object in the box, however it will show that it's been selected.

[image]

`voornaam` has a `valueField = 0`, and while it still correctly adds it to my `this.definitionDetails.Groupings` it's not showing it in the MultiSelect (it only shows the user selected it). When I change `[valueField]="'Type'"` to `[valueField]="'Name'"` it does show it in my MultiSelect.

Any fix for this?

Comment: Getting this same issue, did you every find a fix?

Comment: Hi @Nicolas  did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @NickRubino Did you manage to find a fix for this?